# Using ScopeIdentity for an identity column in a stored procedure, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've created a stored procedure and I'm inserting values into 3 tables, `Users`, `Workers` and `Vets`. In the `Users` table, I have an identity column `UserID`, which is a foreign key to the `Workers` and `Vets` table.

When inserting into the `Workers` and `Vets` tables, I can't seem to retrieve the value of the `UserID` that was inserted into the `Users` table.

This is the stored procedure for the vets:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIntoVets]
    @PrimeiroNome Varchar(20),
    @NomeDoMeio Varchar(50),
    @Sobrenome Varchar(30),
    @DataDeNascimento Date,
    @EndereçoPostal1 Varchar(120),
    @EndereçoPostal2 Varchar(120),
    @Cidade Varchar(100),
    @Especialidade_id Int,
    @Clinica_id Int,
    @UserID Int OUTPUT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Veterinarios([Primeiro nome], [Nome do meio], Sobrenome, [Data de Nascimento], [Endereço Postal1], [Endereço Postal2], Cidade, Especialidade_id, Clinica_id, UserID)
    VALUES (@PrimeiroNome, @NomeDoMeio, @Sobrenome, @DataDeNascimento, @EndereçoPostal1, @EndereçoPostal2, @Cidade, @Especialidade_id, @Clinica_id, @UserID)

    SET @UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

C# code:

```
// Vets
SqlCommand sqlCommandVets = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommandVets.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCommandVets.CommandText = "InsertIntoVets";

sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@PrimeiroNome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (primeiroNome.Text.Trim());
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@NomeDoMeio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (nomeDoMeio.Text.Trim());
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@Sobrenome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (sobrenome.Text.Trim());
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@DataDeNascimento", SqlDbType.Date).Value = (dataDeNascimento.Text.Trim());
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@EndereçoPostal1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (enderecoPostal1.Text.Trim());
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@EndereçoPostal2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (enderecoPostal2.Text.Trim());
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@Cidade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (cidade.Text.Trim());
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@Especialidade_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (dropDownEspecialidade.SelectedValue);
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@Clinica_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (dropDownClinica.SelectedValue);
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

sqlCommandVets.Connection = con;
```

Here you have a screenshot of both the `Users` and `Vets` table:

[UsersTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCZC9.png) AND [VetsTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rat0.png)

I hope I was clear and provided enough info.

Thank you in advance,
Hugo Silva.

Comment: ¿Where are you trying to ge+t the output parameter? ¿how the insert is executed?

Comment: I was searching on the web and in some website they said that you must declare it as an output which I didn't really get why. I just want to get the value that was inserted into the users table for the vets.

Comment: If you use `SCOPE_IDENTITY() ` after inserting `Veterinarios`. it will give you identity value of `Veterinarios` table not `Users` table. check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an OUTPUT parameter for this. Just change your stored procedure that inserts the user data into

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIntoUsers]
    .....
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Then you could execute the stored procedure with `ExecuteScalar` and get the result from the stored procedure that consist of a single row with a single column

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommandUsers.ExecuteScalar());
```

At this point you have the value for the `UserID` column that you want to set in the Vets and Workers table. Just pass it as a normal parameter to your stored procedure.

Also in this context where you have multiple updates to your database you should be sure to insert everything inside a [Transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/local-transactions). If something goes wrong in the insertions of Vets you want to [Rollback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayx5s0h(v=vs.110).aspx) everything you have done in the Users and Workers table or [Commit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx) if all goes well

Comment: How am I suppose to pass it as a normal parameter? Don't I need to declare some kind of value to it? I can't just do                             sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add("@UserID",SqlDbType.Int);

Comment: If I understand your logic correctly, you first insert a record in the Users table. This is where you want to get back the value stored by the database in the IDENTITY column. This value is then passed in the following calls as a parameter in the same way you do it now. No OUTPUT clause needed

Answer (score 0):

Even though many others will recommend returning via a `SELECT` statement, I would recommend sticking with the `ExecuteNonQuery()`. It is more efficient for both the SQL Server as well as your calling application because no database object will need to be created and no object will need to be utilized (directly or transparently) to read it.

I generally explicitly declare my output parameters and then attach them. After the ExecuteNonQuery() you can access the parameters via the .Value property.

Note 1: .Value is an object, so be aware of the *NULL* possibility

```
SqlParamater opUserID = new SqlParameter("@UserID",sqlDbType.Int);
opUserID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
sqlCommandVets.Parameters.Add (opUserID);

sqlCommandVets.ExecuteNonQuery();
int NewUserID = (int)opUserID.Value;
```